# Медленная загрузка JavaScript на IIS 10

Tags: javascript, windows, сервер, iis

Приветствую! У меня на IIS 10 есть 10 JS файлов по 5-10 КБ. При заходе на сайт (Если пользователь не имеет кэша (То есть CTRL+ F5)) сайт грузит по 10-20 секунд каждый JS файл. А остальные CSS, IMG (Которые 2 мб) за 2 секунды и меньше.

Как мне настроить эту систему так чтобы все работало быстро? Объединить JS в один пробовал. Не получается, сайт просто выдает в консоли сотни ошибок (В F12 Google Chrome) и JS файлы не подгружаются.

Есть способы как все оптимизировать?

Вот скрины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка если превратить JS скрипты в один:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _сайт просто выдает в консоли сотни ошибок_ - какие например? добавь скрин, на котором видно, что действительно маленькие js файлы грузятся долго

Comment: @Grundy Я добавил скрины.

Comment: Последовательность скриптов в файле имеет значение. + Проще загрузить один файл, чем много-много маленьких. Уходит больше времени на сам запрос-ответ с сервера, чем собственно на загрузку каждого из них.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270834/asp-net-mvc-bundle-not-rendering-script-files-on-staging-server-it-works-on-dev

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что данные файлы используют устаревший движок. Например, браузер парсит html5 новым движком, а для совместимости использует более старый движок для html4.

В результате скрипт, который использует устаревшую модель DOM, компилируется заметно медленнее, чем мог бы, если бы использовал более новую модель.